# Moving a sefer torah - requirement to read three times

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, torah-reading

[Rema Orach Chaim 135:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.135.14?lang=bi) permits one to move a *sefer torah* to be used in a jail as long as it placed there a day or two before it is used.

I have a recollection of a custom to require a plan to read from a *sefer torah* at least three times in a new 'temporary' location (e.g. a *shivah* house) in order to allow it to be moved there.

Does such a custom exist, and what is its source?

Comment: I recall there being a list of 3's that people think are true but aren't.  1) this 2) someone who makes 3 shidduchim is guaranteed Olam Haba and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: footnote 5]

The sources in note 5 discuss this leniency. They include the [aruch hashulchan orach chaim 135:32](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7705&pgnum=240), shaarei efraim and igrot Moshe.